# Pass JSON data from a .NET WebHandler to redraw Pie Highcharts with new series data

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I want to create a page displaying a default pie chart and a few buttons. When the user clicks on the buttons, the page will get new JSON data from a `WebHandler` and redraw the chart. I'm using .net 2.0, C#, web forms.

I have this `WebHandler` `json.ashx` generating the JSON:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {        
    String data = String.Empty;
    data += "[{\"Male\": 80.0}, {\"Female\": 20.0}]";
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(data);
}
```

Here is my script on the aspx page:

```
    var chart = null;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' (' + this.percentage + '%)';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' (' + this.percentage + '%)';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: [['Yes', 60], ['No', 40]]
            }]

        };

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


        $("#Gender").click(function () {
            $.get('json.ashx', function (data) {
                options.series = data;
                var chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);
            });
        });

    });
```

when I click on the `Gender` button, it does not generate the new chart. How do I properly parse the JSON data and feed it to the `series.data` of the new pie chart?

Comment: Don't  form your json string manually. Use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) etc.

Comment: I'm on .net 2.0 though. DataContractJsonSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer don't support 2.0. I don't really want to use third party framework.

Comment: **c#:** `data += "[{\"Male\": 80.0}, {\"Female\": 20.0}]";`  , **JS:** `data: [['Yes', 60], ['No', 40]]`. Is your `data` an array of object or array of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I got the problem resolved. I had to pass in the Json format that highcharts want.

eg: [{"type" : "pie","name" : "Fruits","data" : [["Apple",43.0],["Pear",57.0]]}]